# Javascript dynamic function to turn array into object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am looking to turn an array that looks like this

```
['group1/ Child 1', 'group1/ Child 2']
```

into an object dynamically that looks like this

```
{
     "attributes": {
          "group0": "group1/ Child 1"
          "group1": "group1/ Child 2"
     }
}
```

the function should allow the array to be

```
['group1/ Child 1', 'group1/ Child 2', 'group1/ Child 3']
```

and return ... and etc

```
{
     "attributes": {
          "group0": "group1/ Child 1"
          "group1": "group1/ Child 2"
          "group2": "group1/ Child 3"
     }
}
```

I think I should be using a reduce function to achieve this, but haven't been able to get it right yet.

Comment: `but haven't been able to get it right yet.` Can you edit your Question to show what you tried?

Comment: That is a really *bad* output structure. You should not have property names that have a sequential number at the end. It really means you want an array, which is what you had from the start. Don't do this.

Comment: @trincot It could be worse. Sometimes, devs use numbers in natural language, like `id="seventh"`, `id="threehundredandeightythird"`

Comment: I wouldn't normally do this, but it has to be this way to work with keycloak and cloudflare.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use reduce

```js
const data = ['group1/ Child 1', 'group1/ Child 2', 'group1/ Child 3']
const grouped = data.reduce((acc,item,i) => {
   acc.attributes[`group${i}`]  = item;
   return acc
},{attributes:{}})
console.log(grouped)
```

But why not just keep the array?